# How to prove: $\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Let $f:\left[0,\infty\right]\to \left[0,\infty\right]$ be locally integrable. It is integrable on every compact subinterval $I \subset  \left[0,\infty\right]$, and assume that the improper integral:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\,dx$$ converges and is finite. Compute:

$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx $$

The limit exists because the integral exists by comparison test for each $y$ and is decreasing function of $y$. I am sure that the answer is zero but I am not allowed to use the Dominated convergence theorem to solve this question, therefore I need either use $\epsilon$ $\delta$ definition or need to bound this integral and apply squeeze theorem somehow.

Comment: Сan you use the uniform convergence of the integral?

Answer (score 7):

The idea is to split $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx$ into two parts: The integral over $[R, \infty)$ becomes small with large $R$ because $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\,dx $ is finite, and then the integral over the bounded interval $[1, R]$ becomes small with large $y$.

For all $R > 0$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx &= \int_{1}^{R}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx + \int_{R}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx \\
&\le \int_{1}^{R}\frac{f(x)}{y^2}\,dx + \int_{R}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{y^2} \int_1^R f(x) dx + \int_{R}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\,dx \, .
\end{align}
$$

Given $\epsilon > 0$ we can first choose $R > 1 $ so large that
$$
\int_{R}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2}\,dx < \frac 12 \epsilon 
$$
and then $y_0 > 1$ so large that
$$
\frac{1}{y_0^2} \int_1^R f(x) dx < \frac 12 \epsilon \, .
$$
Then
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx  < \frac 12 \epsilon + \frac 12 \epsilon = \epsilon
$$
for all $y \ge y_0$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I put a lot of effort but I could not recognize $\frac{f(x){x^{2}+y^{2}<\frac{f(x)}{y^2}$ it is clear now after using this.

Answer (score 5):

As I suggested in comment, let's rewrite $\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} = \phi(x)\psi(x,y)$. Using, that improper integral from $\phi$ exists and $\psi $ is monotone and bounded by $x$, then we can conclude uniform convergence of $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx$. Now it is enough to enter the limit under the integral and get the answer.

Comment: The upper limit of this integral is infinity, the uniform convergence has no help to switch the limit and integration.

Comment: @MathFail. Which integral has upper limit infinity?

Comment: OP's integral, from $1$ to infinity, even though it is uniformly convergent, you can't switch limit and integration.

Comment: @MathFail. Sorry, but I asked about "upper limit" from your previous comment - are you saying that $\int\limits_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2}dx$ has upper limit infinity?

Comment: This is corrrect. If the improper integral is uniformly convergent as shown here with Abel's test, then you can switch the limit and integral.  When $F_n(y) = \int_1^n g(x,y) \, dx$ converges uniformly to $F(y) =  \int_1^\infty g(x,y) \, dx$, then continuity of $F_n$ implies continuity of $F$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{y \to y_0}F_n(y) = \lim_{y \to y_0}\lim_{n \to \infty}F_n(y)= F(y_0) $.  This can be extended for limits as $y \to \infty$.

Comment: See The Elements of Real Analysis by Bartle.

Comment: I can, also, add Fikhtengolts 'Course of Differential and Integral Calculus', II, 2003, page 765.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle A=\int^\infty_{1}\frac{f}{x^2}dx$, since $f\ge 0$, we have $0\le A<\infty$

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N_1>0, s.t.  ~\forall n\ge N_1\Longrightarrow\int^\infty_{n}\frac{f}{x^2}dx<\frac\epsilon2$$

Take $N_2>0$, such that, $\displaystyle\frac A{N_2^2+1}<\frac\epsilon2$, next, let $N=\max(N_1, N_2)$, and when $y\ge N^2$, we have

$$\begin{align}\left|\int^\infty_{1}\frac{f}{x^2+y^2}dx-0\right|&=\int^N_{1}\frac{f}{x^2+y^2}dx+\int^\infty_N\frac{f}{x^2+y^2}dx\\
\\
&\le \int^N_{1}\frac{f}{x^2+N^4}dx+\int^\infty_N\frac{f}{x^2}dx\\
\\
&\le \int^N_{1}\frac{f}{x^2+x^2N^2}dx+\frac\epsilon2\\
\\
&\le \frac1{1+N^2}\int^\infty_{1}\frac{f}{x^2}dx+\frac\epsilon2\\
\\
&=\frac A{1+N^2}+\frac\epsilon2\\
\\
&<\epsilon
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, {\rm d}x = \int_1^y \frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, {\rm d}x + \int_y^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, {\rm d}x \, ,$$
it suffices to prove that $F(y)=\int\limits_1^y \frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, {\rm d}x$ vanishes as $y\rightarrow \infty$, as the second integral clearly does. If $F(y)>0$ would not vanish as $y\to\infty$, then the integral $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac{F(y)}{y} \, {\rm d}y$ diverges. However,
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{{\rm d}y}{y} \int_1^y \frac{f(x)}{x^2+y^2} \, {\rm d}x=\int_1^\infty {\rm d}x \, f(x) \int_x^\infty \frac{{\rm d}y}{y(x^2+y^2)} = \frac{\log 2}{2}\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2} \, {\rm d}x < \infty$$
by Fubini's theorem.